# In Angular, how to display original data and filtered data on the same page?

Tags: angular

Let's say I have some data from a service call, and I store it as `originalData`.

Now in addition, I must filter the data and also display that filtered data. The way I'm doing that is like this:

```
this.service.getData((data) => {
  this.originalData = data;
  this.filteredData = data.filter(/* some filter condition */);
});
```

I have `originalData` and `filteredData` bound on the html template. This solution works. As I require more and more of the filtered versions to be displayed, so I'm storing more and more of these filtered or otherwise modified objects on my class.

This seems like a bad practice, as the state of my class is increasing and getting out of control, and managing the different copies of the data is getting cumbersome.

What would a better practice be?

Comment: I added some more info on custom pipes to my answer. I hope it is clear now what I meant in the comments. If so, consider also accepting the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Transforming data

You want to just transform the existing data. Here are two very simple examples on how to do that, both synchronously and asynchronously. Since usually the data from a service is async.

#### Synchronous

For synchronous data you can just use a function that takes your data as a parameter and returns the desired form of your transformed data.

component.ts:

```js
data = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

divisibleBy20(numbers: number[]) {
  return numbers.filter(number => number % 20 === 0)
}
```

component.html:

```html
{{ data }}
{{ divisibleBy20(data) }}
```

#### Asynchronous

For asynchronous data RxJS provides tons op operators to pipe the data. You can find more operators [here](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators).

Service.ts:

```js
getData() {
  return of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
}
```

Component.ts:

```js
all$: Observable<number[]>
evens$: Observable<number[]>

constructor(
  private dataService: DataService
){}

ngOnInit() {
  this.all$ = this.dataService.getData()
  this.evens$ = this.all$.pipe(
    map((numbers: number[]) => numbers.filter(number => number % 2 === 0))
  )
}
```

Component.html:

```
{{ all$ | async }}
{{ evens$ | async }}
```

Here is an example for you to play with on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vjfdpb?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Here is an example of [what NOT to do](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-obcrg9?file=src/app/app.module.ts) according to the Angular documentation.
These kind of pipes have their uses, but can be triggered a lot for no reason. To prevent this u can make custom pipes 'pure'. This way Angular executes the pipe only when it detects a pure change to the input value.

You can do this by adding `pure: true` to the decorator:

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'myPipe',
  pure: true
})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer. I thought about doing it this way, but I saw this on the angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#do-not-add-filtering-and-sorting-logic-to-pipes

Although I'm not using a pipe here, it's the same result, the filtering would be triggered many times and potentially slow things down right?

Comment: Ah yh, I understand how that could be confusing. The pipes they are talking about there are not the same. They are talking about angular pipes. The ones you create using `ng g p my-pipe`. They aren't the same as RxJS pipes. RxJS pipes are fine to use. They are just explaining that you need to implement things like filter and sort function on your own. For instance there used to be a built in sort pipe in AngularJS, which had major drawbacks. This was because of the template re-rendering, and not just the transforming of data. You might want to read about Pure/Impure Angular Pipes.

Comment: In short people use RxJS pipes to transform data all the time. It is the preferred way over subscribing.

Comment: I think there may be further confusion actually. I didn't mean to link the docs as a reason not to use the RxJS pipe. What I meant was that the docs seem to be indicating that we shouldn't perform filtering logic when data is bound (as in with a pipe on the template), because that logic may be performed many times.

The intention of the article seems to be that if filtering and sorting happens many times, then those calculations should be performed ahead of time. But in my case, I'm not sure how to do that without storing copies of the data.

Sorry if any of that is confusing.

Comment: I get what you mean, still my answer stands. There is no drawback to filtering your data in an RxJS pipe. You can't make applications without doing so. What makes an 'Angular' pipe heavy on performance is that they update not only when the data changes but also when the template rerenders a component. It has to do with changedetection. It is totally ok to use filtering in functions or RxJS pipes. If you don't understand why, you can just take my word for it. XD

Comment: I added an example of what not to do according to the Angular documentation for clarity, [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-obcrg9?file=src/app/app.module.ts). These sort of pipes (custom pipes) can sometimes be triggered 100 times per second for no reason. RxJS pipes only trigger when the data changes.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. I'll mark your comment as the answer. However, I just had one further question. So rxjs pipes are fine, they only trigger once. Angular pipes are not great because they trigger many times, this makes sense, but you mentioned that it's totally ok to use filtering in functions. But the synchronous example you provided would trigger many times right? So ultimately my q is, why is the angular pipe filter not good, but the function filter is?

Comment: The function only is triggered by changes in data, which is what you want. Not by the DOM re-rendering, which is useless when the data hasn't changed. If you want to show the user something useful instead of raw data, you can't get around having to transform that data when needed. It should not have a noticeable impact as long as you don't filter 1000s of records. In that case you might want to look for a solution in the back end (and page the data).